# Does the `IDispatch::GetTypeInfo()` interface thow?

Tags: c++, com, atl, throw, idispatch

I'm trying to find information on if the `IDispatch` interface throws, specifically if `IDispatch::GetTypeInfo()` does.  IIRC, `IDispatch::Invoke()` can, but I can't seem to find anything on the subject and the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/supporting-idispatch-and-ierrorinfo?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(OAIDL%2FIDispatch)%3Bk(IDispatch)%3Bk(DevLang-C%2B%2B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/idispatchimpl-class) doesn't mention anything about this.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, according to the links that I posted, it's part of ATL.

Comment: `IDispatch::Invoke()` cannot throw either.  If it invokes a function of some object and that function tries to throw across a COM boundary it's undefined behaviour  (COM functions should not leak exceptions)

Comment: Easy answer, COM interfaces are never allowed to throw.  Exception handling is impossible to do correctly across language runtime boundaries.  One basic reason that every IDispatch interface method **must** return an HRESULT, "it didn't work" is the most important detail.  Language bindings are free to turn the HRESULT into an exception, they routinely do so.  Even in C++ when you use the #import directive.  Fwiw, having to squeeze the failure of a complicated library function into a single error code is the primary reason why COM+ lost the middleware war to Java and why UWP is having trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*None* of the standard COM interfaces will throw. COM was designed to be language agnostic, including languages that don't have exceptions.

It's entirely possible that the implementation of a COM object might throw, but that's up to the implementation of the object itself. Normally a COM object will indicate an error by returning an error code for its HRESULT.

Comment: `IDispatch` is a C++ wrapper for the COM interface, so I figured that it would implement a throwing mechanism.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, ah, I thought that was weird.  Yes, I'm looking at `OAld.h` which is part of `Windows Kits` (`c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\OAIdl.h`), which I'm assuming is part of the VS install.  I'm guessing that MS didn't do anything wild and make it throw as that would prolly be confusing to C/C++ devs.

Comment: `IDispatch` itself is NOT a C++ wrapper, it is just another COM interface like any other.  You are likely using a C++ wrapper that **implements** `IDispatch`, but that is a separate issue.  COM implementations are not allowed to throw.  But wrappers that *consume* COM interfaces MAY throw when they detect COM errors being reported (see the [`_com_error`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ye3k36s.aspx) class in ATL, the [`COMException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comexception(v=vs.110).aspx) class in .NET, etc)